# Introducing someone who has more than two duties

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

I am looking for words or idioms. I want to say something like this:

> "I won't let you see my grave," Tom, enemy as well as a friend, said.

(So, Tom is my enemy. At the same time, he is my friend.)

Comment: Enemy and friend? Don't you think it should be 'rival'? Just a suggestion though -  '. . . Tom, my rival and friend, said.

Comment: How about... said Tom, both my friend and my foe.

Comment: @shin Thanks for your comment, but the sentence was just an example :(

Comment: @ohio818 Thank you for your idea. I think that would work !

Comment: @Jason, as provided in the example, you may use the conjunction 'and'.